# What's the best way to secure a flexing storm door jamb?

Tags: storm-door

I have an Andersen dual arm storm door. The springs are so strong and the way the installer put it up is causing the door jamb it’s attached to flex and pull nails out. This is causing the door to be misaligned with a larger gap on the bottom lock side than at the top lock side. It’s also making so that the latch no longer engages with the catch. I’m not sure how they installed the jamb as I see no visible nails. I’ve attached some photos showing the gaps and then showing the piece and how it moves as the door opens and closes. What’s the best way to go about fixing this?

[video showcasing problem](https://imgur.com/a/8E7x4c3)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: better explanation of moving pieces]

Comment: I’ve added a new picture with arrows pointing out. I hope that helps. If I can provide any better pictures let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what those pieces are. They appear to be parts of a modular jamb assembly. I'm not familiar.

Comment: That is what I assumed as well. This is my fathers old house and he had this door installed a few years ago. I assume they used those to give clearance between the main door and the storm door. This is only the biggest issue I see from this method. The other was the two giant gaps between door frame and the trim they never filled. Real good insulation technique.

Comment: I'm still struggling with context. Is this a dual sidelight unit? Are there _two_ jamb extensions added to the mullion between the operable door and the sidelight? I'd kill for a full scene shot.

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive. Adding full pictures.

Comment: If this was installed recently, I would call the installer back and have them adderss the issues.

Comment: It unfortunately was not. This was my dads old house and now mine. He had it installed a few years ago.

Comment: Are the struts not adjustable?  Maybe try some other struts?  Or maybe a single strut would pull on the frame less?

Comment: I’m not sure if they are or not. I was thinking of grabbing some long woods screws and sinking them into all three modular pieces for more stability. The weak point seems to be the connection between the outermost module and the middle one. I can’t tell if they are nails or screws holding them together but whatever they are, they are skinny.